# After adding action in url, not getting .css and .js files

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am making an application. If my request with url: http://localhost/invoice/public_html/index.php/string-inventory
Everything works fine.

If I request with url: http://localhost/invoice/public_html/index.php/string-inventory/new-record or http://localhost/invoice/public_html/index.php/string-inventory/

My application doesn't server right .css or Js. I solved this type of  issue from index.php ( no css and js files ) to index.php/ ( with css and js files ) while redirecting to whole different page. But that's not the right way to do. And I am getting 404 for .css and .js files for many pages with same context.

If I comment

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*.css$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*.js$ [NC]

Then there is 404 but the file is not being served

My .htaccess

## Turn rewriting on

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect requests to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.js$ [NC]

#RewriteCond $1 !^(../src)

 RewriteRule .* index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

My expected url for .css should be 
http://localhost/invoice/src/css/mystyles.css

Where it is 
http://localhost/invoice/public_html/src/css/mystyles.css

but If there is not action after controller it works fine. and I do get served expected file. Same for Js.

Need anything, just ask

Comment: Embed your external assets using URLs that start with a `/`, so that they always refer to the domain root - that is the easiest way to fix this (IMHO).

Comment: So I should refer my assets with respect to root?
I am using MVC here, not sure how to do it, since every request is being directed to index.php

Comment: No, not every request - your RewriteConds exclude specific file endings. (Although the more common approach would be to base that decision on whether or not what was requested physically exists as a file or folder.) By referring to your assets from the domain root with a leading slash, you take the path of the current document out of the equation. (That is what is causing your problem here, you changed the path depths the main document is requested from, so all relative URLs will be resolved against a different base.)

Comment: .htaccess if I am not mistaking
I should just check if the request is  not for file and folder and if not then reroute to index.php?

Comment: You should add you advice as an answer. It did solved my problem but I had to keep asking for functions.php, router.php, routes.php on the base of old root which was dirname(dirname(__FILE__)). I didn't mentioned it so, your solution does applies as an answer. thnx

Answer (score 0):

I can not look into your filestructure but it appears your /invoice is your project url, and the folder 1 up from public_html is actually your public root folder.

I can recommend you adapt your apache settings (usually /etc/apache2/sites-available) for your project in a way that the public_html folder is the actual public folder. This will solve the above issue.

Another tip for your .htaccess file. You can check before you rewrite if the requested url is not in fact an existing file (!-f) or directory (!-d) instead of having to define every possible filetype in a list.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [NC,L,QSA] (or whatever rewrite you want to do)
```

Comment: I did converted on the .htaccess code that you gave but I didn't moved as you said. thnx